# A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected - For Integer datatype Oracle .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am getting this error:

> {"ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"}

while calling my stored procedure:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(GlobalVariables.CommandTimeOut)))
{
    ds = DataHelper.FillDS(dataAccessLayer, GlobalVariables.ConnectionString, "pr_my_proc", new Dictionary<string, DlmsParameter>() { 
        { "pc", new CustomParameter() { Name = "pc", ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, ParamType = "VARCHAR2", Value = pc} },
        { "sp", new CustomParameter() { Name = "sp", ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, ParamType = "VARCHAR2", Value = sp }},
        { "pt", new CustomParameter() { Name = "pt", ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, ParamType = "INT64", Value = Convert.ToInt64(pt)} },
        { "rt", new CustomParameter() { Name = "rt", ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, ParamType = "VARCHAR2", Value = rt } },
        { "rv", new CustomParameter() { Name = "rv", ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input, ParamType = "VARCHAR2", Value = rv.ToUpper() } }
        },
    new string[] { "AD" });
}
```

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_my_proc
(
    pc VARCHAR2,
    sp VARCHAR2,
    pt NUMBER,
    rt VARCHAR2,
    rv VARCHAR2,
    RS1 OUT ReturnType.GenericRecordSet
)
```

Executing the stored procedure with `exec` command runs successfully, however calling it from C# code is causing the error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the values and data types that you are passing to your stored procedure; the complete code for your procedure; and the full error message (including details of which line of the procedure the error occurred in). If you don't tell us what is going into the procedure or what is happening to cause the error and where then it is very difficult (impossible?) to debug it. Please help us to help you and provide all the information necessary with the question.

Comment: The code you have shown seems to be passing custom parameters to a custom function of yours. We have no idea what they do.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters' names aren't descriptive so it is difficult to guess what you might actually be passing to the procedure.

However: error you got (ORA-01858) is raised when working with *dates*. I presume that some of `varchar2` parameters might contain it, represented as a **string** which is then - within the `pr_my_proc` - *converted* into a true `date` datatype value. Oracle, however, fails in doing that because value you provided doesn't match date format.

For example:

```
SQL> select to_date('09-oct-2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual;
select to_date('09-oct-2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Today's date really is 9th of October 2023, but - I passed month **name** to `to_date` function, while format model expects two digits for month (`mm`).

I'd suggest you to check what you're passing to the procedure, especially as you said that it works OK from a **different environment** where - presumably - default date format matches value you pass to the procedure.